# I want to calculate the number of active requests through starting time and completion time column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data for Starting time and completion time of client requests in columns. I want to get another column with the values for the number of active requests during the specific time in the row.

I could not figure out how to add this condition in my case.

```
    Request ID  Starting Time   Completion time
           1    16:14:53        12.411
           2    16:15:12        29.065
           3    16:15:17        53.485
           4    16:15:22        62.471
           5    16:15:32        68.908
           6    16:15:32        68.908
           7    16:15:32        68.867
```

Starting time is the clock time(HH:MM:SS), Completion time is in Seconds. This is actually the time server received the request from client and then took some number of seconds to process and complete the request. Now I want to know in another column, how many active clients were there when the specific request arrived. I need values in new column for the number of active requests that have started but not completed yet. Starting time will always be in ascending order.

Comment: "... number of active requests during the specific time in the row." What specific time in what row? Can you also clarify the time formats you use? particularly for Completion Time? What is `12.411` twelve days and 10 hours? twelve hours and 25 minutes? 12 minutes and 25 seconds?

Comment: Is starting time always sorted? Could you count the number of blank cells in the completion time column?

Comment: Do a search on here for similar questions, this is but one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/27968064/4961700

Comment: Starting time is the clock time(HH:MM:SS), Completion time is in Seconds. This is actually the time server received the request from client and then took some number of seconds to process and complete the request. Now I want to know in another column, how many active clients were there when the specific request arrived. I need values in new column for the number of active requests that have started but not completed yet. Starting time will always be in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

In Column D i used this formula to calculate the end time

```
=B2+(C2/86400)
```

In Coulmn E i used this formula to calculate the number of tasks that would have started before the current task was completed

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8;">"&$D2)
```

This was the output i got. You would have to extend the range in CountIf to capture the entirety of your data set.

```
RequestID   StartingTime    CompletionTime  EndTime      TasksStarted   
1           04:14:53 PM     12.411          04:15:05 PM  6  
2           04:15:12 PM     29.065          04:15:41 PM  0  
3           04:15:17 PM     53.485          04:16:10 PM  0  
4           04:15:22 PM     62.471          04:16:24 PM  0  
5           04:15:32 PM     68.908          04:16:41 PM  0  
6           04:15:32 PM     68.908          04:16:41 PM  0  
7           04:15:32 PM     68.867          04:16:41 PM  0
```

Comment: Excel is not accepting this formula =COUNTIF($B$2:$B$8;">"&$D2) . In the column E, I need data for current requests that are not completed on this specific moment of ROW. In row 1 the first value of column E will be 0 because this is the first task and there are no pending tasks. I need to monitor on each row that how many previous tasks are running at this moment

Comment: Not entirely clear on what you meant. If this doesnt work for you then maybe upload a sample of what you would expect the resulting data to look like


=COUNTIF($D$2:$D$12;"<"&$D2) will check the entire list of events (change D12 be the last row with data in your data set).

    =COUNTIF($D$2:$D2;"<"&$D2)  will check for events up to and ending at the current row.  As for the error you encountered with the formula. I suspect you need to change the semicolon ";" to a comma "," .